# SQL Azure + Entity Framework - What's the Pattern?

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

Due to the goofy SQL Azure timeouts and connection resets, are people really using Entity Framework with SQL Azure? Are LOB applications being developed against SQL Azure? If so, are people really implementing re-try patterns all through their data access code? Is there any guidance around this? Sorry for all the questions, use-case just comes off a bit obtuse.

Comment: This question has a proposed answer on the MSDN forum with details on connection patterns for the Entity Framework and more. For anyone interested in the answer, refer to: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/3a9ed384-5374-438e-a8a4-ff4bd8000738](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/3a9ed384-5374-438e-a8a4-ff4bd8000738)